# Is it better to set timeout for HttpGet and HttpHead method when the timeout setting already done at HttpClient level?

Tags: java, timeout, httpclient

We have the following code to talk to our website, and we have timeout threshold set at the HttpClient level to make sure "we don't wait for long time for get response back.". Does the code good enough to satisfy the requirement above? Do we need additional timeout setting for the HttpHead method as well?

```
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // the time it takes to open TCP connection.
        httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, this.timeout);

        // timeout when server does not send data.
        httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT, this.timeout);

        // the head method
        HttpHead httphead = new HttpHead(url);

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httphead);
```

Comment: Have you read the JavaDoc for `HttpClient`, and the subsequent classes you mention?

Comment: yes, but I didn't get a clear clue. do u have any pointers that clearly answer the question?

Comment: I would think the timeout you provide to `HttpClient` is for the connection, and the timout you provide to `HttpHead` is for the request. You might need to test this in your Integration Tests.